# Run FastAPI inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, web-scraping, scrapy, fastapi

I am deploying a web scraping microservice in a Docker container. I've used Scrapy and I am exposing an API call using FastAPI that will execute the crawler command.

I've created a docker container using Ubuntu as the base and installed all required dependencies. Then I use 'exec container_name bash' as an entry point to run the FastAPI server command. But how do I run the server as a background job?

I've tried building from the FastAPI docker image (tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6) but it fails to start.

Comment: Have you looked at the fast api documentation about deploying with docker? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/

Comment: Once you are in bash, You need to execute your server with gunicorn. Put your dockerfiles in your question we can't help you without that

Comment: Also, you mentioned that the existing docker image "fails to start".  Could you post down how or what error you get? It might be worth debugging that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6 image & installed my web scraping dependencies in there along with environment variables and changing working directory to the folder from which `scrapy crawl mybot` command can be executed.

The issue I was facing with this solution earlier is a response timeout because I am running the above `scrapy crawl mybot` command as an OS process using `os.popen('scrapy crawl mybot')` inside the API function, logging the output, and then returning the response. It is not the right way, I know - I will try to run it as a background job; but it's a workaround for now.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENV POSTGRESQL_HOST=localhost
ENV POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
ENV POSTGRESQL_DB=pg
ENV POSTGRESQL_USER=pg
ENV POSTGRESQL_PWD=pwd
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR "/app"
```

FastAPI Endpoint:

```
@app.get("/scraper/crawlWeb")
async def scrapy_crawl_web(bot_name):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    start = current_time.timestamp()
    print("--START JOB at " + str(current_time))
    stream = os.popen(
        'scrapy crawl %s 2>&1 & echo "$! `date`" >> ./scrapy_pid.txt' % bot_name)
    output = stream.read()
    print(output)
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    end = current_time.timestamp()
    print("--END JOB at " + str(current_time))

    return "Crawler job took %s minutes and closed at %s" % ((end-start)/60.00, str(current_time))
```